# Ansible: want to map dynamic hosts with instance-id's

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

My code : http://pastebin.com/jzrYTR2u

What I want to achieve: My script should dynamically take the hosts with specific tag and perform the above tasks on each host one by one. Currently, I am taking the instance-id from elb_facts module.

What I have achieved till now: My script will take the first instance out from elb, will perform the deploy tasks, add back to elb. hosts file is currently hardcoded with IPs

Comment: Please don't use external ressources to "show" your sources. If those links become invalid, the question loses important information for later users searching SO.

Answer (score 0):

Use the boto api to make a connection with AWS and use filters to find the instances you want. You can then recursively search through the list to get the instances and then the instance id's. An example below to make the request for filtered instances:

```
filters = dict()
filters["tag:Profile"] = node["profile"]
filters["tag:Environment"] = environment
filters["availability_zone"] = region + node["distribution"][index]["zone"]
filters["tag:ServiceName"] = node['service_name']

instances_aws = aws_connection.get_all_instances(filters=filters)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the information @Niall Whelehan. I gathered the instance id from elb_gather_facts. I want to map the instance id and the public ip of the server, deploy on that specific host.